# How did the spell around the Palace of the Prophets work?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

So, I've been re-reading the Sword of Truth series, and I realized that this bothered me the first time I read it. The spell around the Palace is some sort of time spell. But how does it work exactly? In one book it makes me think that time is slower in the palace (20 years outside = 1 inside I believe was the ratio Warren gave.) Other times, I think that all it does is slow down the aging process. Is there any more explanation anywhere of how this spell actually works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The palace was placed under a *[bifurcated web](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Bifurcated_web)* spell. This is essentially a spell woven in upon itself.

It combines both additive and subtractive magic to create two distinct shields. The first (outer) shield allowed those inside it to exist in the world of life. The second (inner) shield connected those inside it to a parallel world which allowed those inside to have their life extended. You simply age slower while inside this web spell than those outside of it, about 10 times slower.

In the TV series it was treated as 7 years went by while Richard only spent half a year in the palace. So time dilation existed in the palace according to TV.

Answer (score 1):

It's a life-extending spell, although the wording used in the books implies there's more of a time element to it.

Richard doesn't spend very long in the palace (relative to it's more permanent occupants) and there's none of the basic tropes displayed with regards to time dilation (missing time, day/night out of sync, losing track of people).  He only clues into what's going on when he hears the amount of time he's expected to stay, and wonders what kind of life he could possibly have left afterwards.  My impression of the Sisters is that they have been there so long and have adapted so completely to this state that they take it for granted, and simply don't notice how life fades for other people.

My memory is fuzzy as to specifics (pages, dialogues) as I have not read Stone of Tears in quite some time, so correct me or submit another answer as needed.

Comment: That's the way I feel it reads at times as well. Though, they don't really mention the loss of time and such, at times during the description I still get a dilation feeling.